# If hash has collision, can a password have the hash of another?

Tags: php, encryption, hash

I have a little doubt.

I'm not so expert in encryption or hashing but I know that the hash can have some collision, that is two different text inputs can give the same hash string.

So.. this means that (also remotely) two password can give the same hash and so one user can make a login with another password (because the hash is the same)?

Comment: "some collision" is practically zilch. Not going to happen.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But CAN it happen? i want know only yes or no? ULTRA-remotely but can happen? I want know if "the logic" is true

Comment: Yes, it can happen. But even for hash algorithms where collissions are easier to achieve (md4 or md5), you're not going to be able to construct a textual string that resembles another password. You'd likely need to craft a lengthier binary input string to the hash function to get accidental matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's mathematically improbable but possible.

Answer (score 1):

It can happen, not likely.  I use ripemd320 because as of when I started using it, it had never been hacked.  Which equates to meaning it generates very unique hash codes.

It's not all that important because 25% of passwords can be guessed within 15 minutes.  Less if you know the user's dogs, kids, and spouse names and birth dates.

The point is if someone does get your user database with hash codes it is easy to attempt a hack with a poor hashing algorithm.

The way to hack it is to generate a hash code for all the common passwords and see if it matches the stored hash.

It was stated by some government security agency years back that there was no known successful hack of this type when ripe320 was used.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and it is known to happen with poor hash functions (think crc32). Chances of it happening with modern hash functions are, indeed, practically zero. The chances of guessing the right password using some sort of dictionary attack are considerably higher.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter if an attacker can find collisions when hashing passwords. A user knowing multiple passwords which are valid is not a problem.

In fact for PBKDF2 and scrypt, which are both popular and recommended password hashes, finding collisions and second pre-images [is easy](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/pbkdf2-hmac), but you need quite a bit of imagination to come up with [scenarios where this matters](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.security.phc/1271/focus=2370).

What matters is that:

1. Given a hash it's hard to figure out the password (first pre-image resistance)
2. Collisions are rare enough so they don't reduce password entropy much. Any decent hash with at least 128 bits of output fulfills this one.
3. It's expensive to compute, slowing down password guessing attacks. This means you can't
4. It's salted, preventing multi target attacks.

See [How to securely hash passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords) on security.se for details.